Pegar columnas en ultima fila en apps script
estoy intentando que una columna que siempre tendré en "V1:V8", se me pase a otra hoja y se me pegue en la ultima fila y en la casilla "Q", tengo esta formula pero no consigo que al grabar mas de uno se pegue consecutivamente:
function copiarColumnas() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('V1:V8').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Planning'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('Q3').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Formulario!V1:V8').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);

Gracias,

Hola. Tu pregunta no se entiende. ¿Qué quieres decir con no consigo que al grabar mas de uno se pegue consecutivamente?

Buenos días, cuando pego en la celda "Q1" y es un pegar de 3 celdas, que en la siguiente vez que activo el pegado empiece en la celda "Q4" y así sucesivamente

Copiar: Formulario!V1:V8
Pegar:  Planning!Q consecutivamente.
Propuesta:
function copiarColumnas() {
  /** Obtener Clase SpreadSheet */
  const classSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  /** Obtener Class Range */
  const classRangeFormulario = classSpreadSheet.getRangeByName('Formulario!V1:V8');
  /** Obtener Class Sheet */
  const classSheetPlanning = classSpreadSheet.getSheetByName('Planning');
  /* añadir línea */
  if (classSheetPlanning.getLastRow() <= classSheetPlanning.getMaxRows())
      classSheetPlanning.appendRow([' ']);
  /** Obterner Clase Rango Pegar Colunma Q=17*/
  const classRangePlanning = classSheetPlanning.getRange(
            classSheetPlanning.getLastRow(),17,classRangeFormulario.getNumRows(),classRangeFormulario.getNumColumns());
 /* Copia y Pega valores, fórmulas, formatos y combinaciones. */ 
 classRangeFormulario.copyTo(classRangePlanning, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false)
}

Puedes cambiar rango ejemplo:

'Formulario!V1:V8'
'Formulario!V1:V10'
'Formulario!V1:V3'
'Formulario!V1:W10'

Referencias:
Class Spreadsheet Acceder a archivos de Hojas de cálculo de Google y modificarlos Las operaciones comunes son agregar hojas nuevas y colaboradores.
Método getRangeByName(name) Muestra un rango
Class Sheet Acceder a hojas de cálculo y modificarlas Las operaciones comunes consisten en cambiar el nombre de una hoja y acceder a los objetos de rango desde la hoja.
Class Range Accede a los rangos de las hojas de cálculo y modifícalos. Un rango puede ser una sola celda en una hoja o un grupo de celdas adyacentes en una hoja.
Método appendRow(rowContents) Agrega una fila en la parte inferior de la región de datos actual en la hoja. Si el contenido de una celda comienza con =, se interpreta como una fórmula.
Método getLastRow() Muestra la posición de la última fila que tiene contenido.
